# "Move to meta" Off-Topic Close reason, ship should be grey?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, arqade-migration

The spaceship in the "Vote To close -> Off Topic" has the full color of the main site:

[image: Vote to close dialog]

Shouldn't this be grey like the meta icon?

[image: gaming meta icon]

Example from Super User showing the grey meta icon:

[image: super user grey meta icon]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should indeed. The [image file path](http://cdn.sstatic.net/gamingmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png) is the correct one, but that file contains the colored version. It will be replaced by the correct one in the next build.